# Recode continuous into continuous variables (without split function) in R

Tags: r, recode

I am trying to recode a set of data that cannot be easily done with the split function or ifelse function. How would I recode the following data?

1 --> 1
2 --> 0
3 --> 0
4 --> 1
5 --> 1
7 --> 0
8 --> 1

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Not clear what your input is.

Comment: This is data from a variable in a pre-existing data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(car)
v <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
recode(v, "c(1,4,5,8) = 1; else = 0")
```

Or as per mentioned by @zx8754 you could use `ifelse()`:

```
ifelse(v %in% c(1,4,5,8), 1, 0)
```

Which gives:

```
#[1] 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Another approach:

```
x <- +(x %in% c(1,4,5,8))
#[1] 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
```

The `+(..)` nomenclature is a method to coerce a logical vector to integer the same way that `as.integer(..)` would.

Comment: `ifelse` is more general, but if OP really has a mapping into 0/1 output, this is the best approach. BTW `+` is the "R slang" for converting a logical into an integer parsimoniously.

Comment: I agree. There's no need for `ifelse` if this is the desired output. You wouldn't say `ifelse(condition, TRUE, FALSE)` since it is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this? Although continuous-to-continuous usually implies some type of function that could be applied.

```
x <- c(1:5, 7:8)
x
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 7 8

x[x == 1] <- 1
x[x == 2] <- 0
x[x == 3] <- 0
x[x == 4] <- 1
x[x == 5] <- 1
x[x == 7] <- 0
x[x == 8] <- 1
x
# [1] 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
```

Comment: Easier: `x[x %in% c(2,3,7)] <- 0; x[x %in% c(1,4,5,8)] <- 1`